# Think Python Ch12 Ex 4: Code seems correct but hangs when compiled

Tags: python, freeze

Was trying this exercise from the book think python. *Write a program that reads a word list from a file (see Section 9.1) and prints all the sets of words that are anagrams.*

My strategy is to get file, sort each word and store in a list of strings (called listy). Then I'll look through the original list of words again and compare against listy. If same, store the sorted word as key and un-sorted word from original file as value in a dictionary. Then simply print out all the values under each key. They should be anagrams.

The first function I created was to generate listy. Have broken down the code and checked it and seems fine. However, when I compile and run it, python hangs as though it encountered an infinite loop. Could anyone tell me why this is so?

```
def newlist():
    fin = open('words.txt')
    listy = []
    for word in fin:
        n1 = word.strip()
        n2 = sorted(n1)
        red = ''.join(n2) 
        if red not in listy:
            listy.append(red)

    return listy

newlist()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the hang. Can you show the words.txt that is problematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `set` to check for whether the word has been preocessed or not:

```
def newlist():
    with open('words.txt') as fin:
        listy = set()
        for word in fin:
            n1 = word.strip()
            n2 = sorted(n1)
            red = ''.join(n2)
            listy.add(red)
    return listy

newlist()
```

You could even write it as:

```
def newlist():
    with open('words.txt') as fin:
        return set(''.join(sorted(word.strip())) for word in fin)

newlist()
```